# PostgreSQL: Role postgres does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo, postgresql-9.3

I have install Postgres 9.3 with pgAdmin form [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) on ubuntu,

that is working fine . i create  user name is **postgres** and password is also **postgres** .

then install odoo 8 from bitnami after that my postgres 9.3 (previous) server is not connecting and giving following error :

> `PostgreSQL: Role postgres does not exist`

Comment: With which name you are create PostgreSQL user?

Comment: i dont remeber actually . I have created python script that connect to that database . from their i found the user name postgres and password is also same and database name is eko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of error came when System User don't have access rights to start Odoo server/ Postgres server.

To avoid those kind issue, we should alter role for *System User.*

Try with this:

1. Open Terminal and fire this command => *sudo su postgres*
2. Enter password for *postgres* System user
3. createuser postgres -s
4. psql template1
5. alter role postgres with password 'postgres';
6. \q
7. Restart Odoo server

Comment: when i am trying 3rd command  psql template1 then it is giving error : psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

Comment: that'y I ask for a system user name. Try with updated answer. Start odoo server with *postgres* system user.